# There is an unknown repo in my github profile. how to remove it (theres no settings option)

Tags: github

There is an unknown repo in my github profile. how  to remove it (theres no settings option)

i tried everything like leaving from all the organizations but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the main page of that repo
Check Settings and select Danger Zone.
Delete Repo.
Maybe you need to commit with the Repo Name, i'm not sure yet.
This should work :)

Comment: as i already said there's no Settings option on the main page of the repo.

Comment: Have you tried opening the URL directly?
https://github.com/<NAME>/<REPO>/settings in a Private Browser?
You will get a 404 first but after Login to Github you should be in the SETTINGS of that Repo.
Scroll down to the bottom of the page and you are there .
The missing SETTING could be caused by a render error on the webpage by using some "Blocker" or hardened security settings of the browser.

Comment: omg didn't know my lil adblocker could cause site rendering issues. I removed the adblocker extension and the settings option is showing up now. Thanks mate